# How to extend sales order grid using event observer?

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, sales-order, order-grid

I was extending my magento sales order grid and I was having an error with it because of a conflict with the other extension on rewriting the grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Configure your extension to observe event 'core_layout_block_create_after'.

The best way to add a new column to the orders grid is to use event observers. In our case, we are going to use event 'core_layout_block_create_after'. To add an observer for this event we need to edit file /etc/config.xml of your custom module.

app/code/community/MyCompany/MyModule/etc/config.xml

```
<config>
...
<adminhtml>
    <events>
        <core_layout_block_create_after>
            <observers>
                <magestyapps_ordergrid_add_columns>
                    <class>MyCompany_MyModule_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>addColumnsToGrid</method>
                </magestyapps_ordergrid_add_columns>
            </observers>
        </core_layout_block_create_after>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
...
```

2. Create an observer for the event

The next step is to create the observer class with the observing method in it:

app/code/community/MyCompany/MyModule/Model/Observer.php

```
<?php

 class MyCompany_MyModule_Model_Observer
{
/** 
 * Add new column to orders grid
 *
 * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
 * @return $this
 */
public function addColumnsToGrid(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();

    // Check whether the loaded block is the orders grid block
    if (!($block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid)
        || $block->getNameInLayout() != 'sales_order.grid'
    ) {
        return $this;
    }

    // Add a new column rigth after the "Ship to Name" column
    $block->addColumnAfter('coupon_rule_name', [
        'header' => $block->__('Coupon Rule Name'),
        'index' => 'coupon_rule_name',
    ], 'shipping_name');

    return $this;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this blog. It will help you to extend sales order grid using observer.

1) http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/extend-magento-sales-order-grid-using-event-observer/

2) https://www.magestyapps.com/blog/post/how-to-add-a-custom-column-to-order-grid-in-magento/